# Avoid output numbers x> in file executing batch file

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a batch file that execute this

```
@echo off
ECHO. > "Salida.txt"

for %%G in ("Backup\"*.sql) do osql -S SERVER -U name-P password -i "%%G" 

for %%G in (*.sql) do ( 
ECHO !TIME! Ejecutando "%%G"... >> "out.txt"
osql -S SERVER -U name-P password -i "%%G" >> "out.txt" 
)
```

It works perfectly fine. But in the output file I see numbers like
`1> 2> 1> 2> 3> 1> 2> 3> "Real output"`

I know that this is a normal behavior when the output is redirected.
I'm searching for a way to avoid printing this numbers.

Comment: If you run `where osql`, does it return an .exe file or a .bat/.cmd script?

Comment: I'm totally new into to this and I don't understand your question.